# Обрезать строку регуляркой

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строки, в которых нужно вырезать регуляркой слова (слово - это текст разделенный пробелами, или текст от начала и до пробела, если речь идет про первое слово в строке.) которые содержат три и более цифры (цифры могут стоять не подряд, внутри слова)

Исходные строки:

```
X04000083670 Полотенцесушитель Водяной Cube 500 x 1200 W RAVAK
4660059930312 Полотенцесушитель электрический Terminus Виктория П7 450x750 черный RAL 9005 матовый
104SCS6610 Держатель разъемный для п с 1 10 100 шт упак
```

В результате должно получится:

```
Полотенцесушитель Водяной Cube x W RAVAK
Полотенцесушитель электрический Terminus Виктория П7 черный RAL матовый
Держатель разъемный для п с 1 10 шт упак
```

с помощью регулярки удалили, такие данные:

```
X04000083670, 1200, 500 
4660059930312, 9005, 450x750 
104SCS6610, 100
```

Задачу пытаюсь решить в обычном текстовом редакторе **notepad**, обработка списка регулярным выражением через поиск-замену.

Comment: Предоставьте регулярное выражение, которое Вы используете. Исходя из Вашего описания "слов" почему в первой строке 1200 должно удалиться, а 500 нет? Опишите по каким правилам удаляются численные значения. Исходя из примера удалённых слов можно ли сделать вывод, что первое "слово" в строке всегда удаляется?

Comment: @XelaNimed Да, вы правы, поправил в первом сообщении. Сейчас никакое регулярное выражение не использую. По этому и написал сюда, с просьбой о помощи.

Comment: @OlegAliev, почему во второй строке осталась 7?
В последней строке удалилось 100, а 1 и 10 остались?

Comment: @ksa с семёркой там всё нормально и с последней строкой тоже, в условии же написанно что нужно удалить слова у которых есть три и больше числа. Тут вопрос в другом, почему одно слово `450x750` посчиталось за два слова.

Comment: @ksa, 7 осталась, потому что цифр в слове должно быть не менее 3 штук.

Comment: @ksa, 450x750  - поправил

Comment: @OlegAliev вы не так поправили :) слово `450x750` нужно полностью удалить

Comment: @ksa, да вы правы, исправил

Answer (score 1):

Вообще задача конечно интересная, но на мой взгляд идеально ее с помощью регулярных выражений не решить. Вот вариант, довольно близко приводящий текст к тому что нужно. Но не идеально.

```
/[.*?\d+.*?]{3,}/gim
```

Основаная мысль, в том что ищем что угодно, лишь бы там была цифра. И таких "что угодно" должно быть три или больше.

Пример есть здесь: https://regexr.com/758ea

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой вариант...

```js
const arr = [
  'X04000083670 Полотенцесушитель Водяной Cube 500 x 1200 W RAVAK',
  '4660059930312 Полотенцесушитель электрический Terminus Виктория П7 450x750 черный RAL 9005 матовый',
  '104SCS6610 Держатель разъемный для п с 1 10 100 шт упак'
]
const re = /^.+?\s|\d{3,}(\S*?\d{3,})?/g
const a = arr.map(s => s.replace(re, ''))
console.log(a)
```